# What are the proper precaution for using cow's milk to feed babies?

Tags: toddler, food, feeding, nutrition, milk

There's a [great guide for using pumped breastmilk](http://www.askdrsears.com/topics/breastfeeding/while-working/storing-transporting-breast-milk)...in it, there are tons of guidelines for:

- How long it can be kept after it has been heated up?
- If a baby didn't finish a bottle, how long before you have to toss the remaining milk?
- etc.

Is there such a guide for cow's milk? I couldn't find a comprehensive site like the above for it. I found a [related question](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/q/1295/1922) here, but it only address one case...heating up the milk.

NOTE: My daughter is older than 12 months.

Comment: Cow's milk is for baby cows, not baby humans.

Comment: @DA01: You're right - but that doesn't explain why kids and adults enjoy so many dairy products. Someone brought human dairy products to market and it flopped - I wonder why!

Comment: Well, cow's milk isn't really designed for adult humans either, though a portion of the population has managed to adapt. The whole topic of milk in general is rather fascinating, though obviously a bit off topic.

Comment: That said, I just noticed that the question states the child is OLDER than 12 months. I initially read that as under 12 months. As an addition to a proper diet, it's fine. Just make sure it's not a replacement for proper human milk/formula when that's the primary diet.

Comment: Sorry @DA01, the question initially was misleading because it mentions pumped breast milk which is usually for younger infants. :)

Answer (score 11):

**If your child is younger than 12 months, I would refrain from giving cow's milk altogether**, see [What Happens If a Newborn Drinks Cow Milk?](http://www.livestrong.com/article/515068-what-happens-if-a-newborn-drinks-cow-milk/) and [Cow's milk: When and how to introduce it](http://www.babycenter.com/0_cows-milk-when-and-how-to-introduce-it_1334703.bc). Problems which can occur are *nutritional deficiencies* (most commonly *iron deficiency*), *gastrointestinal irritation* or *allergic reactions*. In general, babies' digestive tracts and kidneys are not yet ready

Living in Germany, [UHT-milk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UHT_milk) is quite common, which can be stored up to nine months, if not opened. Then it should be consumed within a couple of days - one week works fine for us at home including our three-year-old.

**For a day out**, I recommend using a *vacuum flask* together with *drinking cups*; as of 1 year our son as well as all children in our nursery school were well able to use that instead of a bottle.

**We generally dispose all "unfinished" drinks at the end of the day**, I would do likewise with an unfinished bottle (i.e. keep it one day maximum).